# How to add ui frameworks to a c# form

Tags: c#

overflow, im having trouble trying to add a ui framework , for exmple metro framework, to my c# form.

I know that i have to include the reference and include it with

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
```

but im not sure what else to do here and when ever i try and google it, i just get websites that try and sell me a framework package.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;


namespace FrameworkTest
{
public partial class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I know this may be a silly question but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/#GettingStarted

Comment: @Crowcoder No i haven`t I shall have a look... thank you

Comment: @Crowcoder I see where i went wrong, i should have put `public partial classs Form1 : MetroForm` Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Crowcoder I found out that I was supposed to add
MetroForm after Form1 like:

```
public partial class Form1 : MetroForm {
   //Code goes here
}
```